# Jhipster : entity added, exception on Mapper object at application startup

Tags: jhipster

I am using Jhipster generator master version.
I have added an entity with `yo jhipster:entity collaborateur`.
Everything ran well.
I have imported the project into Eclipse.

When I run my application I am getting this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'collaborateurResource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myapp.rhapp.web.rest.mapper.CollaborateurMapper com.myapp.rhapp.web.rest.CollaborateurResource.collaborateurMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myapp.rhapp.web.rest.mapper.CollaborateurMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at com.myapp.rhapp.rhappApp.main(rhappApp.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)  

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myapp.rhapp.web.rest.mapper.CollaborateurMapper com.myapp.rhapp.web.rest.CollaborateurResource.collaborateurMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myapp.rhapp.web.rest.mapper.CollaborateurMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 20 common frames omitted  

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myapp.rhapp.web.rest.mapper.CollaborateurMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Is it a known issue? or something wrong about my project configuration?
Thank you

**[update]**

I create a project with yo jhipster.
I ran `mvn compile`
Then I ran `mvn` to start the project (no use of eclipse yet)
I am getting this error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Adresse déjà
>   utilisée  at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:186)    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainer.start(UndertowEmbeddedServletContainer.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>     at com.rhapp.rhapp.RhApp.main(RhApp.java:70)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.net.BindException: Adresse déjà utilisée     at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
>     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
>     at
>   org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.java:190)
>     at
>   org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:243)
>     at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:142)    ... 15 common
>   frames omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DTO Mappers are generated by MapStruct annotation processor, you could run `mvn compile` to generate them first and make sure `target/generated-sources` is linked as a source folder in Eclipse.

http://jhipster.github.io/configuring-ide-eclipse/

http://jhipster.github.io/using-dtos/

Or maybe there is a way to configure Eclipse to run MapStruct annotation processor automatically.

**Update**

You can see the error message "Adresse déjà utilisée", so look whether you have another process listening on port 8080 (maybe Tomcat) and either stop it and re-start your app or edit your `application-*.yml`, set `server.port` property to something else than 8080 and re-start your app.

Comment: ok, thank you. I have followed the configuration of eclipse instructions. Now I have another error.  (see update main post)

Comment: yes I figured out that by changing 8080 to 8181 it solved the problem. But when I scan the ports, there is not 8080 opened....